# Do I need to replace the entire floor?

Tags: bathroom, water, hardwood-floor, damage

Water damaged wood floor butting up to tub. Small hole has rotted through. 2 boards next to it are ever so slightly raised/off. This is all confined to a small location, approximately 6x6. The rest of the floor is in great shape. What are my best options? [image]

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no need to replace _all_ the flooring to fix a small area like that. However, there's a possibility that the water has damaged the base of the wall, the sub floor and/or joists so you'll probably need to remove a larger portion just to do some exploratory work to see what other damage needs to be repaired. Careful work will allow you to remove the flooring so that it can be reused, except for the damaged portion, which would be replaced.

Comment: If you have the tools and time then you can remove the damaged portions, glue in new hardwood, sand it, stain it, and seal it to match the surrounding floor to the best of your abilities. If you do not possess the tools, time, nor knowledge then I would estimate a professional would fix this for about $150-$200. Do consider that additional, hidden damage may have occurred so if you want to fix it all then the price will simply get higher :-)

Comment: That looks like tongue-in-groove.   Google: How to Repair a Tongue-and-Groove Wood Floor | This Old House for a video that will show you what is involved.